# How to show huge data

Tags: java, asp.net, .net, windows, web

I am having very huge data. That I want to show in browser (Web app), But while loading browser is crashing.

Basically Its a grid that has row and column header and rest of the grid is having check boxes, that  user will click based on row and column header values.

when I am loading this data its going up to 2gb and total data will be 5gb. any one can help me how can I show this much data in browser or in any type of app(windows or web app) or any type of technology.

Comment: try using pagination with grid view

Comment: What kind of user would click through 5GB of checkboxes?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the pagination technique to show the data in part.

So it will reduce the load on page but will increase the database hit.

Comment: actually its a permission grid from where admin will assign the permissions. and why we cant put pagination because its a folder structure in column header if permission got changed on root folder that means all child folder also will get affected. so this we need to show.

Comment: I suggest brainstorming with the user on how you're going to design the UI. For example I have thousands files inside hundreds of subfolders in my source code. I won't even able to comprehend every single file, nor will I care about them. Your UI *will* involve paging and/or filtering because you won't even able to show all of them anyway. Try asking at [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) for ideas

Answer (score 0):

One class that may help you is the `GZIPInputStream` and `GZIPOutputStream`. It sounds like you're using text data so compressing what you're sending should drastically cut down the amount of data that the client has to download.

Comment: The data probably already is gzip compressed (or deflated) during transmission, and the end result is the same. Trying to display 5GB of data in the browser will not work, no matter what you do.